# SQL: Deleting rows from table based on columns selected from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select rows in a table identified by the values in two columns. The values are found in another table. An example should help:

Table1

```
A | B | C
101 1   x
102 1   o
103 1   o
```

`SELECT A, B FROM Table1 where Table1.C = 'o'`

Returns:

```
A | B
102 1
103 1
```

I want to delete rows in Table2 where A and B match those returned by the query on Table1.

Table2

```
A | B | D
101 1   Not deleted
102 1   Deleted
103 1   Deleted
```

Becomes:

```
A | B | D
101 1   Not selected
```

The first select works, but I can't see where to go from there. I currently have the following, but it's throwing an error and I'm not clear what I should be doing. Tutorials welcome as I'm new to SQL.

```
DELETE Table2
    where A, B in
        (SELECT A, B FROM Table1
    where Table1.C = 'o')
```

Comment: Your first query will only return the 102 row. Can you confirm your input and output data please?

Comment: Sorry, typo now fixed. It should return 102 and 103 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify more than 1 field in the `where` part when you are using the `IN` clause as in your query. Instead, you can do this:

```
delete t from 
table2 t
inner join table1 s on t.a = s.a and t.b = s.b
where s.c = 'o'
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FGXQJ87315)